# Prove that $\log^\alpha n = o( a^n )$

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

Please, how to prove:
$\forall c \in \mathbb R_+$ $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb N_+$ $\forall n \ge n_0 :$ $log^\alpha n < c \cdot a^n$ for $ \\a>1$, $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ ?
Thanks

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: I tried to split it into two branches:  
1) $\alpha \le 0$ so there is:  
$\frac{1}{log^\alpha n} < a^n \cdot c$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{log^\alpha n} = 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^n = \infty$ so f(n) is bounded above by 0 but g(n) isn't so can we say here there must exists $n_0$ for every $c$ ?
2) for $\alpha > 0$ I have no idea ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the L'Hopital's theorem we have for $a>1$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{a^{\frac n\alpha}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\alpha}{n\ln a\cdot a^{\frac n\alpha}}=0$$
so for $\epsilon >0$ there's $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that for $n\ge n_0$ we have

$$\frac{\ln n}{a^{\frac n\alpha}}<\epsilon\iff \ln^\alpha n<\epsilon ^\alpha a^n=c \cdot a^n$$